# Capture image using camera and send that image as attachment in email : Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to capture image using camera and send it as attachment in Email.

I tried everything on Internet nothing is working for me. If anyone could help with code please.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            File  file = savebitmap(thumbnail);
            sendMail(file);
        }


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


private File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "abcd" + ".jpg");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
        file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "abcd" + ".jpg");
    }

    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return file;
}

void sendMail(File mFile){
    Uri uri = null;
    uri = Uri.fromFile(mFile);
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"abc@gmail.com"});
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share!"));
}
```

}

Comment: post your code in the question of what you've tried

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ComposeEmail)

Comment: @RahulKhurana  i have posted sir, i want to send image captured by camera as attachment in email. My app is crashing

Answer (score 1):

Saving the bitmap:

```
{
    .....
    File  file = savebitmap(thumbnail);
    sendMail(file);
}

private File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
  String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalFilesDir().toString();
  OutputStream outStream = null;
  File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, temp + ".jpg");
  if (file.exists()) {
   file.delete();
   file = new File(extStorageDirectory, temp + ".jpg");
  }

  try {
   outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
   bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
   outStream.flush();
   outStream.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return null;
  }
  return file;
 }
```

//and then

```
void sendMail(File mFile){
Uri uri = null;
uri = Uri.fromFile(mFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {""}); 
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, EMAIL_SUBJECT); 
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, EMAIL_BODY);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share!"));
}
```

Comment: I tried this code Earlier : instead of FILENAME i put ("file://" + "abc") .                        abc  is a jpg file in sdcard

Comment: @SukhchainKharoud you need to get absolute path of the file not just "abc"

Comment: i have posted my code sir ,  and can  directly send bitmap to  email attachment ?

Comment: File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, temp + ".jpg");      Sir what is temp? its showing error on temp. @YashKrishanVerma

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();      My android studio is showing getExternalStorageDirectory (Striked a line cutting it and showing : getExternalStorageDirectory()' is deprecated less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: Reports where deprecated code is used in the specified inspection scope.

Comment: App clicks a picture and then crashes

Comment: Use getExternalFilesDir() intead of getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: i have updated my code  getExternalFilesDir() doesnot exist , i mean when i type it, it shows  in red , doesnot work . i get no suggestion from android studio to get it in code

Comment: @RahulKhurana could you please help

Comment: @SukhchainKharoud see this: stackoverflow.com/a/9975439/4079010

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from internet 
https://androidexample.com/Camera_Photo_Capture_And_Show_Captured_Photo_On_Activity_/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=77&aaid=101

I am assuming you may not handle permission just like above link

when you run your app in 6.0 above like marshmallow device then need permission other wise no need to permission. that time your code work..

if run marshmallow device that time need permission then make below code ..

```
private void alertDialog(){
    CharSequence menu[] = new CharSequence[]{"Take From Galery", "Open Camera"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick a Picture");
    builder.setItems(menu, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if(i == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "galery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();

}
```

then above method put in permission code like below ..

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(webView.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(webView.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                    alertDialog();
                }
                else{
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(webView.this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
                }
            }
```

add two permission into manifest file ..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

your error main problem is permission if you add this below line is work.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(webView.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(webView.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                    alertDialog();
                }
                else{
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(webView.this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
                }
            }
```